# Import statement with respect to efficiency and multiple function definitions

Tags: python

I have a basic question with respect to efficiency involved in programming in Python.

Suppose in a single file, around 20 different functions have been defined. Some functions are very specialized and import some specific modules which are not needed by other functions.

1. One option is to have all the import statements in the beginning of the file.
2. The other option is to have import statements specific to each function embedded in the function definition itself

Which is a better practice with respect to code efficiency and in general with respect to good pythonic practices ?

Comment: [*"Imports are always put at the top of the file"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 1):

Stylewise imports should be placed at the top of the file as per [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), however there are occations when you might want to break the style (and there are occations where the standard libs do this as well if I recall correctly).

Imports will execute as a regular statement when executing the code where they're put. This means that imports at the beginning of the file will execute when the file is read (ie imported), but if it's put in a function it will execute whenever the function is called.

This would give a performance penalty whenever the function is called, but note that the actual import is only done once. If the function is unlikely to be called there may be a benefit of postponing the import by putting it in the function that uses it (especially if it's a slow loading module).

I can see no good reason why you would put the import in another place than those you've mentioned. And breaking the coding style for no reason is not a good idea.

Bottom line is that except for special occations you should have all import statements at the beginning of the file (it gives better performance 999 times out of 1000 and is more pythonic 10 times out of 10).